# A priori estimatives of the heat equation on bounded domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u \in C(\bar{\Omega})$. Suposse $u \in C^{2,1}(\Omega \times (0,\infty)))\cap C(\bar{\Omega}\times [0,\infty))$ is a solution of

$u_{t}-\Delta u=0 \ in \ \Omega \times (0,\infty)$

$u(.,0)=u_{0}$ on $\Omega$

$u=0$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$

Prove that

$\sup\limits_{\Omega} |u(,t)|\leq Ce^{-\mu t}\sup\limits_{\Omega}|u_{0}|$ for any $t>0$

where $\mu$ and $C$ are positive constants depending only on $n$ and $\Omega$.

My strategy for this problem is find a integral representation of solution of this problem as well as the case of the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}\times (0,\infty)$, an idea would be to extend the function $u$ properly, but i don't know how to do this. Any tips?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but at least answers in average. The function $v=e^{\mu t}u$ solves $v_t-\Delta v=\mu v$. Multiplying both sides by $v$ and integrating over $\Omega$ we get $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int v^2=-\int |\nabla v|^2+\mu \int v^2$. By Poincaré inequatity $\int v^2\le C\int |\nabla v|^2$, hence taking $\mu=C^{-1}$ we get $\int v^2\le \int v^2_0=\int u^2_0$. Hence $\int u^2\le e^{-2\mu t}\int u^2_0$.

Comment: One idea is to take large enough multiple $\phi$ of the (positive) first Dirichlet eigenfunction ($\Delta \phi = - \lambda \phi$) so that $\phi(x) > u(x,0),$ and then show $u(x,t) < e^{-\lambda t} \phi(x)$ using the maximum principle. You might need extra regularity assumptions on $\Omega$ or $u$ to show that such a finite multiple exists, though.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can obtain a decaying bound on $\int|Du|^2$, then you should be able to get a decaying bound on $\sup |u|$ using Sobolev embedding/interpolation inequalities. Again, though, I think this needs some boundary regularity assumption.